# bxslider stop on mouse hover custom pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I have a `bxSlider` on my webpage. 
I'm trying to stop slider when mouse hover my custom paginator.
**Here is my html:**

```
<ul id="slider">
    <!-- Slide -->
    <li class="slider-element">
        <a href="'.$sliderLink.'">
        <img src="'.$sliderImage.'">
        <div class="slider-caption-wrapp">
            <div class="slider-caption">'.$sliderTitle.'</div>
        </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <!-- Slide -->
    <!-- Slide -->
    <li class="slider-element">
        <a href="'.$sliderLink.'">
        <img src="'.$sliderImage.'">
        <div class="slider-caption-wrapp">
            <div class="slider-caption">'.$sliderTitle.'</div>
        </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <!-- Slide -->
</ul>
<!-- Paginator -->
<ul id="slider-paginate" class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <li><a data-slide-index="'.$slideIndex++.'" href="'.$sliderLink.'"><span>'.$slideIndexShow++.'</span></a></li>
    <li><a data-slide-index="'.$slideIndex++.'" href="'.$sliderLink.'"><span>'.$slideIndexShow++.'</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is my js;

```
// Main Slider
var slider = jQuery('#slider').bxSlider({
    auto: true,
    speed: 500,
    delay: 5000,
    autoHover: true,
    stopAuto: false,
    pagerCustom: '#slider-paginate'
});
```

Here is what i've tried so far:

```
$(document).on('hover','#slider-paginate',function() {
     slider.stopAuto();
     slider.startAuto();
});
```

Unfortunately it didn't work. What am i missing? What is wrong with my javascript code?

**How can i stop bxslider when mouse is hover on paginator elements?**

Comment: You are calling `slider.stopAuto`, and then `slider.startAuto` directly after that – makes little sense. Did you mean to pass _two_ different callback functions to `hover`?

Comment: @CBroe yes. I want to stop slider when mouse hover paginator elements. then will play when mouse is fly out of paginator.

Comment: Then go check the jQuery documentation for `.hover`, on how to pass a handler function _each_, for both entering and leaving an element.

Comment: @CBroe will check it. Btw i'm not familiar of jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer myself;

i used 2 events;

First one for `hover` and other for `mouseleave`

Solution:

```
$('#slider-paginate').hover(function(){
     slider.stopAuto();     
});
$('#slider-paginate').mouseleave(function(){
     slider.startAuto();        
});
```